# Creating Ext.data.Model using JSON config

Tags: json, extjs4

In the app we're developing, we create all the JSON at the server side using dinamically generated configs (JSON objects). We use that for stores (and other stuff, like GUIs), with a dinamically generated list of its data fields.

With a JSON like this:

```
{
"proxy": {
    "type": "rest",
    "url": "/feature/163",
    "timeout": 600000
},
"baseParams": {
    "node": "163"
},
"fields": [{"name": "id", "type": "int" },
    {"name": "iconCls", "type": "auto"},
    {"name": "text","type": "string"
    },{ "name": "name", "type": "auto"}
    ],
"xtype": "jsonstore",
"autoLoad": true,
"autoDestroy": true
}, ...
```

Ext will gently create an "implicit model" with which I'll be able to work with, load it on forms, save it, delete it, etc.

What I want is to specify through a JSON config not the fields, but the model itself. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
{
model: {
       name: 'MiClass',
       extends: 'Ext.data.Model',
       "proxy": {
    "type": "rest",
    "url": "/feature/163",
    "timeout": 600000},
        etc... }
"autoLoad": true,
"autoDestroy": true
}, ...
```

That way I would be able to create a whole JSON from the server without having to glue stuff using JS statements on the client side.

Best regards,

Comment: mind if I ask what the advantage is of doing it that way?

Comment: Yes, we have a client app with 3500 classes. Almost 1000 are models of all kinds. 99% of the GUI's in the app are created by means of a metamodel, we want to achieve the same with Ext.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. The syntax to create a model class is similar to that of store and components:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyClass', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:[..]
});
```

So if you take this apart you could call `Ext.define(className,config);`
where `className` is a string and `config` is a JSON object and both are generated on the server.

Comment: I'm talking about the definition of the model by using **only** JSON, no eval's nor statements like define() or create()

Comment: When you define a Store you can specify the "name" of the Model it manages. But prior to that you must define the model class via Ext.define(...). I want to define the model class via JSON, not by evaluating anything. 

For some stuff you can define a store just by means of JSON object {...}, use the StoreManager or you can define it somewhere else and then pass the instance to it.

Comment: What I want is the same, but for models. Aparently it doesn't exists.

Comment: I suppose you could just define fields config on the store in lew of models. I don't want to discourage you, but my gut feel is that your efforts are misdirected. It really feels like you are fighting the framework by leaning on the server side a bit too much.

Comment: That's my gut feel too, we're fighting the framework. There's no other way to deal with such a big amount of classes on the server side, which are perfectly handled by means of metaprogramming and metamodels. We want to use all what ExtJS provides, but I can foresee we'll end up using only the widgets and maybe a few features more.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve what I want.
The only way you can do it is by means of defining the fields of the Ext.data.Store and have it to generate the implicit model by using the fields configuration.